# Java. The method isOpen() is undefined for the type Lock. Also need some help fixing some code/debugging

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class GentCPT3
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in)); 

      System.out.println("Enter key");
      int key1 = Integer.parseInt(objReader.readLine()); // set to 111  

      System.out.println("Enter key2");
      int key2 = Integer.parseInt(objReader.readLine()); // set to 222

      Lock lock1 = new Lock (key1);

      Lock lock2 = new Lock (key2);

      System.out.println(lock1.isOpen()); // prints false

      lock1.close();
      lock2.close();
      lock1.open(111); // opens lock1
      lock2.open(222); // opens lock2111
      lock1.open(123); // fails to open
      lock1.open(456); // fails to open
      lock1.open(789); // fails - prints “Alarm”
    }
  }
class Lock //Initializing class
{
  //Initializing variables
  boolean isOpen;
  int key; 
  int numAttempts = 0;

  Lock(int key) 
  {
    isOpen = false; 
    this.key = key;
  } 

  public void close()//for incorrect combo 
  {
    isOpen = false;
  } 
  public void open(int key)//for correct combo
  { 
    if(this.key == key) 
    {
      isOpen = true;
    } 
    else if(this.key != key && !isOpen) 
    {
      numAttempts++;
    } 
    if(numAttempts == 3) 
    {
      System.out.println("ALARM");//prints alarm when the combo is incorrect **enter code here**3 times
    } 
  } 
}
```

I need help fixing the error mentioned in the title. Also a few other debugging things I need help with. feel free to edit the code if you think you can fix it. I need help setting the attempts for each combonation on the lock to 3 because as of right now its set to 2 and I don't know why

Comment: You don’t have a method named `isOpen`, just a field.

Comment: remove parenthesis in `lock1.isOpen()`?

Comment: I tried that and I don't get any errors, however my program doesn't function the way I want it to. I just need some 1 on 1 help tbh

Comment: Also, for good design, you should make your class fields in Lock private and write getter and setter methods for them for other classes to use.

Comment: @JoshuaGentile you can get 100 on 1 help here; all you have to do is update your question with specific issues you are having; explain them to the best of your ability

Comment: @JoshuaGentile what makes you think that *right now its set to 2*?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not closing the locks once you open them successfully. Change your calls to this:-

```
lock1.close();
lock2.close();
lock1.open(111); // opens lock1
lock2.open(222); // opens lock2111
lock1.close(); // NEW ADDITION
lock2.close(); // NEW ADDITION
lock1.open(123); // fails to open
lock1.open(456); // fails to open
lock1.open(789); // fails - prints “Alarm”
```

To further improve the code, reset `numAttempts = 0` in your `open()` when `this.key == key`. And remove `this.key != key` because it is always `true` due to the previous `if` condition.

Comment: so do I remove the parenthesis in isOpen?

Comment: yes, parenthesis are used when you call a method.. but `isOpen` is a field/variable in your code

Comment: so wait, if I remove this.key != key, what do I do with the isOpen in the else if? do I just remove the whole line?

Comment: just leave it there, so it will look like `else if (!isOpen)`

Comment: okay, so I compile it without any errors now but when I run the program. when I type in the correct input, it comes up with false and ALARM. I want it to say that the lock is now open and then end the program

Comment: then remove the last 3 lines in the answer above and add `System.out.println("Opened");` inside your `if (this.key == key)`

Comment: wait, which 3 lines do I remove?

Comment: the ones with the comments `// fails ...`

Comment: see my question in comments of your post.. it gives 3 attempts to me

Comment: remove the parenthesis?

Comment: because I already did that. its just surrounded by brackets now